# OOM in CoroutineWorker when doing Bitmap operations

Tags: android, asynchronous, out-of-memory, android-workmanager, coroutineworker

I am trying to run some work for a set of files (~2000), and I need to decode some, so it takes a lot of memory. If I am 'doing work' like that:

```
override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
     (0...2000).forEach { i ->
         analyze(uris[i])
       }
     return Result.success()
}

fun analyze(uri) {
   val bitmap = decodeBitmap(uri)
 .onSuccess{
      apply color filer()
  }.onSuccess {
   save bitmap to file system() 
  }
 }
```

I am getting OOM in 10 seconds, because decoding, color filtering and saving are async, and e.g. there are 100 bitmaps decoded, but only 10 are color filtered, and memory is overflowed with bitmaps, and then I am getting OOM.

Is there any way to run async operations in Worker without returning?
I reworked all flow to recursion, but it's seems to be impossible to run recursion in Worker. Maybe there are some smart suspend way?

Comment: What does `decodeBitmap` return? Is it a Task?

Comment: It's an async request, and on a successful result, there are more async code run on that bitmap...

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `analyze` a suspend function, that suspends execution while waiting for the async request to complete. Currently, `analyze` returns immediately, which means the 2000 files are being decoded in parallel.

You can use [suspendCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) to achieve that.

```
suspend fun analyze() = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
      val bitmap = decodeBitmap(uri)
 .onSuccess{
     etc...
  }.onSuccess {
      continuation.resume()
  }
}
```

Comment: suspendCoroutine didn't worked out, because ... to use it I had to launch suspend coroutine for each of 2000 files? Anyway, It didn't worked out.
But.

Comment: I defined CountDownLatch with counter == size of files, and I pass ref of latch to each of files (which will latch.countdown in the end of processing); and I count how many I passed and how many is not countdowned(), and if this value is big (e.g. I launched 50, but latch is still 200), so I wait until latch will be 150 in order to continue launching processes. This worked like charm and I now can control on how much of RAM I want to use (until I get onLowMemory callback or OOM)